# pass in a list of labels for generation of figures in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently trying to save figures each with a name coming from a list in a for loop.

Input:

```
 plot_l=['test1','test2',.........]  

for i in range(ydata.shape[1]):
            plt.figure()
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
            ax.plot(dsfg,ydata[i])
            ax.set_xlabel('dsfg')
            ax.set_ylabel('tzui')
            ax.set_title('misc ') 
            secax.set_xlabel('len')
            plt.savefig('plot_l{0}.jpg'.format(i))
            plt.close()
```

Output: The figures are generated but with incorrect figure name, ie,

```
plot_l1.png
plot_l2.png
plot_l3.png
```

Desired Output:

```
test1.png
test2.png
test3.png
```

I have also tried `plt.savefig(plot_l[i]+'.png')` in place of `plt.savefig('plot_l{0}.jpg'.format(i))` Suggestions are welcome....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating on integers generated by `range`:

```
for i in range(ydata.shape[1]):
```

And you are naming the files with this parameter `i`.

```
plt.savefig('plot_l{0}.jpg'.format(i))
```

Assuming there is no error and the list of names contains as many names as there are iteration on `i` (i.e. `ydata.shape[1] == len(plot_l)`), then you can replace the `savefig` with:

```
plt.savefig(f'{plot_l[i]}.jpg')
```

The notation `f` followed by a string is equivalent to `str.format()`, but is more explicit as you can place the variable you are formatting inside the `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am getting strange behaviour. My editor is returning `<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>` 75 times which is the length of my list. However. there are no figures in my folder... If I suppress plt.close() I can see the figures in my editor.....

Comment: I found the problem. There was a colon inside each string in the list. I removed it. The figures are now in my folder. Thanks!